# tensorFlow throws me the error ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to do my first neural network based on the code my teacher gave me but when I try to fit the network I get the follow error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1224 test_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1215 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1211 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1208 run_step  **
    outputs = model.test_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1174 test_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=False)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py:976 __call__
    self.name)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py:158 assert_input_compatibility
    ' input tensors. Inputs received: ' + str(inputs))

ValueError: Layer sequential expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(10, 784) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(10, 10) dtype=float32>]
```

the line that throws me an error is this

```
model.fit( x=x_train , y=y_train , batch_size=10 , epochs=10 , verbose=1 , validation_data = [x_test,y_test])
```

I try changing the brackets by parentheses but it doesn't work

The data is

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import np_utils
import seaborn as sns

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1]*x_train.shape[2])
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2])

x_train = x_train/255
x_test = x_test/255

y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train,10)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test,10)
```

the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim = 784))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Comment: try leaving out the batch_size argument. Else you need to give more details

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Also add the data that I use

Comment: @lautarogonzalez can you show the model summary?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is put the validation data in a tuple instead of a list.

So change this:

```
model.fit( x=x_train , y=y_train , batch_size=10 , epochs=10 , verbose=1 , validation_data = [x_test,y_test])
```

to this:

```
model.fit( x=x_train , y=y_train , batch_size=10 , epochs=10 , verbose=1 , validation_data = (x_test,y_test))
```